# Call a method after a delay of 2 sec

Tags: android

I have a some items in list view. I keep changing focus on items in a list view When i keep a focus on any of the item for 2 seconds in list view call a method. How to do it ?

thanks

Comment: Use handler for achieve this.

Comment: if you to perform some delay then used handler

Answer (score 2):

Use Handler

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         // Call your method OR place your logic here                   
     }
 }, 2000);
```

call method inside `run()` for delay.

Comment: But how to check whether item is focused for more than 2 sec.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **rxjava2** as it has got a bunch of `more cool operators`

In *dependencies* of gradle add :-

```
 implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
 implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.7'
```

and in your code :-

```
 new CompositeDisposable.add(Completable.fromAction(this::YourMethod)
                            .delay(2,TimeUnits.SECONDS)
                            .subscribeWith(yourDisposableCompletableObserver));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // perform your operation.
        }
    },2000);
}
```

Comment: **Call a method after a delay of 2 sec** change it to 2k

Comment: But how to check whether item is focused for more than 2 sec.